# Upload Multiple File In Different Attribute

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.8

How to  upload multiple selected files in different attribute such as **pic_1,pic_2,pic_3** in MYSQL

Views

```html
 <input type="file" name="carEvidence" multiple>
```

Controller

```php
  $this->validate($request, [
            'carEvidence' =>  'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,zip,pdf|max:2048',
        ]);
 $post = new Cars;
 if ($files = $request->file('carEvidence')) {
            $destinationPath = 'public/image/'; // upload path
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $post['carEvidence'] = "$profileImage";
        }
$post->save();
        return redirect('/internalaudit')->with('success', "Has been sent for Validation");
```

Comment: your input type="file" needs to have name as `carEvidence[]` to accept the multiple files as array.  Then use the `foreach` to loop through the array , then store it one by one

Comment: I would accept the answer if this issue solved! :)

Comment: @Steven Attribute means a different database column. Like pic_1,pic_2,pic_3 or else..

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya yes bro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, `different attribute such as pic_1,pic_2,pic_3` for your `cars` single table make you trouble to handle files. My suggestion is, do it using`relationship`. If so, you are storing some information about cars into your `cars` table. And each car may have multiple images for showing as car evidence. In this situation, It would be better you make another table such as `car_evidence` make two columns in this table named `cars_id` and `car_images`. Then make a relationship between them. If you do like this, then you can submit more car images as you want dynamically. **pic_1,pic_2,pic_3** attributes not be better way. Please, have a look to my process - 
Your **Cars.php** model -

```
class Cars extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'cars_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        //your cars table's other fields
    ];

    public function carevidence()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CarEvidence', 'cars_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Make a new model `CarEvidence` with migration by running `php artisan make:model CarEvidence -m`. Then, inside this migration file just add two `columns` like this -

```
$table->bigInteger('cars_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->string('car_images');
```

Your **CarEvidence.php** model should look like-

```
class CarEvidence extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'cars_id', 'car_images',
    ];

    public function car(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cars', 'cars_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

The form is -

```
<form action="your-route-or-url-here" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    //your other input fields about car information here, I think if any
    <input type="file" name="carEvidence[]" multiple>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::post('/your-form-action-url-here', 'YourControllerHere@YourMethodHere');
```

And then in your controller method-

```
public function YourMethodHere(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
             'carEvidence.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            ]);

     $post = new Cars;
     //$post->carEvidence = "yes";here other information about car to save in `cars` table
     if ($post->save()) {
          if($request->hasFile('carEvidence')){
             $files = $request->file('carEvidence');
             foreach($files as $file){
                 $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                 $filename =time().'.'.$extension;
                 $file->move(public_path('/image'), $filename);
                 CarEvidence::create([
                    'cars_id' => $post->id,
                    'car_images' => $filename
                 ]);
              }
          }
      }

  return redirect('/internalaudit')->with('success', "Has been sent for Validation");
}
```

And, finally during return your blade file

```
public function yourmethodname()
{
$cars = Cars::with('carevidence')->get();
return view('your-view-blade-file', compact('cars'));
}
```

Then inside `your-view-blade-file` to get the car images(evidence) you can use nested `foreach` loop -

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">{{ session('success') }}</div>
@endif
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
         <ul>
             @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
             <li>{{ $error }}</li>
             @endforeach
         </ul>
    </div>
@endif


@foreach($cars as $car)
    <p>{{ $car->your-fields-from-cars-table }}</p>
          //and get all relevant images for car by this
          @foreach($car->carevidence as $evidence)
            <img src="{{ asset('image/'.$evidence->car_images) }}" height="60px" width="60px" />
          @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Okay ill try and let u know :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks bro it works! :) Will award the bounty in 5 hrs!

Comment: I am feeling glad, that it's working for you. You're most welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply providing the `multiple` attribute for elements such as this isn't everything you need. When making a multiple-input type, whether it's `file`, `select` or even `input`, you need to suffix the name with `[]`, so in your example, the field would be:

```
<input type="file" name="carEvidence[]" multiple>
```

From there you can cycle through them and upload them appropriately.

Comment: It would be `name="carEvidence[]"` then

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `@ollieread` 's answer, You can loop through the array to store the image or any other uploded file in database or anywhere . 
For getting files as multiple,

```
<input type = "file" name = "carEvidence[]" multiple>
```

Then in your controller file , use the `for loop` to get the every single files .

```
 $post = new Cars;
 if ($files = $request->file('carEvidence')) {
    foreach($request->file('carEvidence) as $file) {
        $destinationPath = 'public/image/'; // upload path
        $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
        $post['carEvidence'] = "$profileImage";
    }
}
$post->save();
```

Simple. Try it and let me know .

Answer (score 1):

follow like this Code : 
**in View file**
 -  `<input type="file" name="carEvidence[]" multiple>`